# Is it possible to undo a review action

Tags: support, review

I just reviewed a proposed edit on a SO question. At first it seemed that the edit was just just "how to" to "how-to". So I rejected the edit. However, my mistake turned out to be that there also was a change to a hyperlink in that edit which was relevant and should be approved. Is there any way to undo my rejection and approve the edit instead?

Comment: No, this is not possible. But that's why we have not just a single reviewer.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd; I did see that question, but my question is about all review tasks.

Comment: OK, Bart and Singer are correct, such thing is not possible.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No, it is not possible to "undo" or "redo" your review. I believe there are two things you can do:

- Deal with it. It takes 3 votes to accept/reject accepted edit, so hopefully the other reviewers will accept it properly. After all, we are all humans and we all make mistakes.
- If the edit happened to be rejected, you can go to the question for which it was proposed and change it yourself. This will not help the guy who proposed the edit (unfortunately), but at least you'll improve the question, so his efforts will not be completely in vain.